# Why is this reference to an ActiveRecord association failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

In Rails 2.2.2
In my model I have this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "t346128_question"
  set_primary_key "question_id"
  has_many :sections, :order => 'position, section_id', :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end
```

And in my controller, this:

```
def answer()
   @question = Question.find(params[:id])
   puts "question=#{@question.name}..."
   puts "sections=#{@question.sections.size}..." # <<== THIS FAILS
   render :layout => false
end
```

The line with @question.sections fails with "uninitialized constant Question::Section"

These lines of code are actually copied from another app where it all works. In database.yml I'm pointing to the same db that app uses.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you have your Section model properly defined as well. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a Section model available. You should also create that model in `app/models/section.rb`.